# How to apply gradient colour along a curve?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

In image 1, I have made an electric spark by applying a displace modifier and cloud texture to a long mesh strip, controlled by a driver following the https://youtu.be/p4UWvg6ixho [tutorial](https://youtu.be/p4UWvg6ixho). I want to apply a color gradient along the mesh's length so that either tips of the spark are blue and the remaining is white. Below are two attempts I did following tutorials. But couldn't figure out the mapping part myself. Any help please.

[image: mesh]
[image: attempt 1]
[image: attempt 2]

Comment: Does your mesh have UVs ? can you show the UV layout ?
if your curve UV goes along the X axis, you can separate X and Y axis with a separate XYZ node and use that for the ramp Input...

Comment: @MasterHeavy Hey! That worked right! When I opened the UV editor all vertices had apparently been collapsed to a point. Corrected it per your instruction and got it right. But on closer inspection only the boarder of the tips have become blue. How may I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the way your mesh was made, it may or may not have an automatically generated UV map. As @ Master Heavy has commented, if it does, you can use a shader tree like this:

[image]

using either X or Y, depending on which dimension of your subdivided plane is the long one.

If the plane does not yet have suitable UVs, then you will have to unwrap it. That may be a supplement to your question .. perhaps the best way to get a clean answer to that would be to share your file on [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: Thank you Robin! Yes I had to unwrap it manually to get the result partially. Unlike the image you've shared my mesh isn't wholly blue at the tips. Rather it's just the edges of tip that change to blue. What could be the reason?

Comment: @jais Probably the mapping.. ideally you would want the map of the faces to be a nice even rectangular grid scaled to fit the UV square 0-1 space in both directions. If you start with a plane, and just scale it in edit mode to get the strip, instead of reducing it to a line and then extruding it again as in the tutorial,it should be mapped like that automatically .. or you could just map the plane from view before scaling, and the UV's will persist when you scale/subdivide.

Comment: @jais Don't add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Oh sorry! I'm new to stack exchange.

Comment: @robin Thank you! Yes scaling did help much in unwrapping. The problem with the tip colouring was due to mixing an emission shader with the gradient. The blue of the graident had to be made darker for the right result.